# Database (database/database.sqlite) does not exist. Database works from artisan tinker

Tags: database, laravel, sqlite, configuration, connection

I created my database.sqlite file in the `database` folder. My `.env` file contents are :

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=absolute\path\to\database\database.sqlite
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=
```

When I run `php artisan tinker` and `DB::table('users')->get();` I get the info from the database.

My DatabaseController is:

```
class DatabaseController extends Controller
{
    public function main()
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')->get();

        return view('database',compact($users));
    }
}
```

Yet when I request `/database` path I get the error:

`QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
Database (database/database.sqlite) does not exist. (SQL: select * from "users")`

UPDATE:
A temporary fix is to change the database.php from the `config` folder:

```
  'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => 'absolute\path\database\database.sqlite', 
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

Instead of using `env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite'))`, which returns `database/database.sqlite` not my absolute path.

Comment: how do your run your server? `php artisan serve` or apache/nginx?

Comment: Use the absolute path to the file in your `.env`

Comment: heh, solution for me was to remove the DB_DATABASE entry from my .env altogether. That way it defaulted to using the database_path() function that correctly allowed my app to interact with the database.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to use full path, something like:

```
DB_DATABASE=/home/laravel-project/database/database.sqlite
```

Comment: simpler way is to use "../database/database.sqlite"

Comment: thats for mac and linux, but windows?

Comment: @wafi With Laravel 7.3, writing "../database/database.sqlite" works for the migration, but when trying to login/register, the database is not found. It's found if reverting to `database/database.sqlite`, but then `php artisan migrate` doesn't find it anymore, so the solution with full path the good one.

Comment: @TuGordoBello for windows use full path replacing single backslash  double backslash \\.    Eg : DB_DATABASE=C:\\Project_Folder\\database\\database.sqlite

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu WSL in Windows the absolute path must include /mnt/c/absolutepath

Stop php artisan serve, config:cache, config:clear, serve

This is what worked for me.

Comment: Adding the absolute path was part of the fix, but also this answer was the other half https://stackoverflow.com/a/54975979/2105095

Answer (score 22):

If you remove `DB_DATABASE=...` from your `.env` file and use the path in the `config/database.php`:

`'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),...`

(if your `database.sqlite` file is in `database/` folder), it will work, too.

Answer (score 11):

I ran the following commands:

`php artisan config:cache`

`php artisan config:clear`

`php artisan serve` - restarted the server

Answer (score 8):

For those who still face this issue: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/database-databasedatabasesqlite-does-not-exist-error-on-running?page=1

Since sqlite only require DB_CONNECTION=sqlite in .env file so you just remove the other:

```
DB_HOST
DB_PORT
DB_DATABASE
DB_USERNAME
DB_PASSWORD
```

then save and run migration again. This was how I solved the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

In config/database.php file:

```
'sqlite' => [
              'driver' => 'sqlite',
              'database' => dirname(__DIR__).'/database/database.sqlite',
            ],
```

Then run following command:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 6):

As [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1193304/chris) said in the comments, the main solution is to **completely delete** `DB_DATABASE` from the .env file (in fact, only the first line of the following code is needed).

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 3):

For Windows, you need to set up your path like this

```
DB_DATABASE="C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\data\\database.db"
```

Answer (score 3):

✅ When using sqlite as your db, remove other DB env variables and it should work fine.

I faced the same problem and this solved it perfectly.

```
DB_DATABASE=sqlite
```

Remove the others.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that the problem here was because of **Homestead**.
Absolute path to the *database.sqlite* file on local machine is not the same as the virtual machine one has.

In my case a had to set:

```
DB_DATABASE=/home/vagrant/code/database/database.sqlite
```

Or, you can just comment out this line and you are ready to go.

```
#DB_DATABASE=
```

Answer (score 1):

In your .env file replace
DB_DATABASE = database.sqlite
to
DB_DATABASE = directory_path/project_name/database/database.sqlite

For example: directory_path: C:/xampp/htdocs/project_name/database/database.sqlite

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

go to the PHP folder from your C: directory and open the file php.ini.
From there find `extension=pdo_sqlite` and remove `;`

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem.
Just had to create the database.sqlite file in the database directory and run my migrations

Answer (score 0):

Hello this has helped me. I hope it could help someone else too.

```
DB_DATABASE=storage/database.sqlite
```

this is in the .env file of course before that just create the file with

```
touch storage/database.sqlite
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easier than it seems. Just install:

```
sudo apt install php-sqlite3
```

Okay, now you can run the command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

The only configuration required in `.env` is:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
```

Comment: [so] is an **English-only** site, but you can use the portuguese version of it: [pt.so].

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Run this commands:

```
  php artisan config:cache
  php artisan config:clear
  php artisan serve
```

Then, You need to use full path, something like:

```
DB_DATABASE=/home/laravel-project/database/database.sqlite
```

Configur In config/database.php file:

```
'sqlite' => [
              'driver' => 'sqlite',
              'database' => dirname(__DIR__).'/database/database.sqlite',
            ],
```

Make Sure

```
DB_DATABASE=sqlite
```